# How to write android test for a recyclerView inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-testing

I have defined a recyclerView inside a fragment and I want to test it.

I know I can use `RecyclerViewActions`to test my recyclerView like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.scroll_view))
.perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(3, click()));
```

But how do I create the fragment in the test class? How do I create the recyclerView in the fragment before I use `recyclerViewActions` statements on it? I've seen a lot of examples on this but none of them gives a complete explanation.

Comment: you will have to write `androidTests`. you cannot create fragment in a unit test, you can mock it out though.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal That's what I meant. I've corrected my question.